# Laravel not retrieving same id mulptiple times Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Trying to retrieve the same id multiple times. Currently the request only retrieves data once, even if there are multiple requests for the same id.

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Page  $page
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $page = Page::find($id);
    $blocks = $page->content; // eg. 1,2,1,1,1
    $blocks = Block::whereIn('id', explode(',', $blocks))->get();
    // $blocks = Block::findMany(explode(',', $blocks));
    dd($blocks); //returns 1 & 2, not 1,2,1,1,1
    return view('pages.show', compact('blocks'));
}
```

Basically trying to get the same resource multiple times.
My view is simple:

```
@foreach($blocks as $block)
    {{$block->title}}
@endforeach
```

I tried findmany and whereIn but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to repeat the same block multiple times, you can't just do that with a query. The DB will simply return those blocks without duplication.

You can map over the blocks' IDs yourself to create a list with the duplicated blocks you want:

```php
$ids = explode(',', Page::find($id)->content);

$dictionary = Block::findMany($ids)->keyBy('id');

$blocks = array_map(function ($id) use ($dictionary) {
    return $dictionary[$id];
}, $ids);

return view('pages.show', compact('blocks'));
```

Comment: I have tried this approach but the return is given an undefined index of 1 in the array map function

Comment: This worked thanks so much! I have weird values in my array so had to use array_filter and str_replace to sort that.. works perfectly your a diamond!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $page = Page::find($id);
    $blocks = $page->content; // eg. 1,2,1,1,1
    $blocks = Block::whereIn('id', array_unique(explode(',', $blocks)))->get();
    dd($blocks); //returns 1 & 2, not 1,2,1,1,1
    return view('pages.show', compact('blocks'));
}
```