# Laravel Eloquent: How to Retrieve Multiple Records for the Same ID?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project where I have an array of article IDs, and I need to retrieve multiple records from the database for the same ID. However, when I use Eloquent, I only get one result even if the same ID appears multiple times in my array.

Here's an example of the array:

```
$articleIds = [5, 5, 5];
$articles = Article::whereIn('id', $articleIds)->get();
```

The result I'm getting is only one record, but I expect to get multiple records since the same ID is repeated in the array.

How can I modify my Eloquent query to retrieve multiple records for the same ID?

I have also tried the below from another [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406860/laravel-not-retrieving-same-id-mulptiple-times-eloquent)

```
Article::findMany($all_ids)->keyBy('id');
        $blocks = array_map(function ($id) use ($all_record) {
            return $all_record[$id];
        }, $all_ids);
```

**I can get the result using a loop but I do not want that result I want an eloquent or query (DB) way result.**

Comment: If this is your array `$articleIds = [5, 5, 5];`  of course you will get collection with on article if you have diff ids array `$articleIds = [1,2,3];` you will get collection with 3 articles of they're exists if course

Comment: @PsyLogic i get your comment sir but i wnat 3 different result even if i send same id

Comment: Well there's always the hard way is to loop on your array which will result 3 queries for your example then you can merge the collection! this is a unique Question actually :D , I'll think about it.. I'll be back if something comes up !

Comment: I have to ask... Why? What is the business logic need for having the same record returned multiple times? And why do you need your database to ignore its own basic functionality, which is when using something like `WHERE id IN (5, 5, 5)` or `WHERE id = 5 OR id = 5 OR id = 5`, it **should** only return 1 record? You can use `UNION` as PysLogic suggests, but again... Why? Why not `$article = Article::find(5);`, then `return [$article, $article, $article];`. This might be a "unique" question, but it really doesn't make much sense from a practical standpoint... Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @TimLewis I am working on one project that required calculating the article price multiple times if the article is selected same article multiple times, the user Select the article 3 times then has to show calculate that cost 3 times, and the same when the user select another article also calculate that multiple time. this is best i can explain it sir

Comment: @always-a-learner It looks like you are working on shopping cart or similar .. why don't you save selected articles in a session with quantity and then multiply quantity with article price ! because your idea isn't practical at all even with UNION Solution.

Comment: Yeah, that scenario is common in e-commerce platforms, and _none_ of them return the same Article (or Product) multiple times... You store the Product and the quantity, then do basic math to determine the price. The approach you're expecting is kinda nonsensical, and goes against how every database operates, so you'll be "shooting yourself in the foot" if you want to continue trying to get it to work that way.

Comment: @TimLewis yes I get your view sir but this is not the case here I think or maybe, I created the module as per modern criteria and following the standard i get to follow,
i am most sure that i am not doing this wrong but as i see you have higher knowledge so i will sure lookinto the way i am processing this. thanks sir

Comment: No modern e-commerce platform does what you're trying to do, and for good reason... When you click a Product, you will _always_ see a "Quantity"  field, that lets you pick how many of the product you would like to order. This is then added to a "Shopping Cart" along with a single instance of the Product, which in turn is multiplied against the Product's price. You're never actually adding X instances of the Product to your cart, nor would you see the same Product listed multiple times on your Order. You say *"i am not doing this wrong"*, but all the comments and answers here say otherwise...

Comment: @TimLewis ok sir then i will delete this stupid question and try something meaningful thanks for the view sir, i will try to level up my skills as i think i am starting from the bottom today again.  please report this question or delete this i have try but this is no allowing me to delete.

Answer (score 0):

A very rough way (as @PsyLogic mentioned) would be to just loop over the array and make a separate query for every ID:

```
$articleIds = [5, 5, 5];
$articles = [];

foreach ($articleIds as $articleId) {
    $articles[] = Article::where('id', $articleId)->first();
}
```

While this approach does "work", It has the potential to cause some serious performance issues when given a large array of IDs.

Comment: Froeach is the last option i choose, i know this way but i want any eloquent or query way.

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is the UNION ALL

```php
if(count($articlesId) === 1){
 DB::table('articles')->where('id', $articlesId[0]);

}else{

$firstId = $articlesId[0];
array_shift($articlesId)

$articlesQuery = DB::table('articles')
    ->where('id',$firstId);

foreach ($articlesId as $id) {
    $articlesQuery->unionAll(
        DB::table('articles')
        ->where('id', $id)
    );
}
 
$articles = $articlesQuery->get();


}
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: The goal is to send one shot and get the results but the foreach or map is required whatever you try